# Pipe to/from the clipboard in a Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, macos, clipboard

Is it possible to pipe to/from the clipboard in Bash?

Whether it is piping to/from a device handle or using an auxiliary application, I can't find anything.

For example, if `/dev/clip` was a device linking to the clipboard we could do:

```
cat /dev/clip        # Dump the contents of the clipboard
cat foo > /dev/clip  # Dump the contents of "foo" into the clipboard
```

Comment: You have tagged this as Linux, and Macos: MacOS does not use Linux. Do you mean Gnu/Linux with X11, Gnu/Linux with wayland, Gnu/Linux at console (no gfx), Gnu/Linux via ssh, or Mac OSX?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

## 2018 answer

Use [clipboard-cli](https://github.com/sindresorhus/clipboard-cli). It works with macOS, Windows, Linux, OpenBSD, FreeBSD, and Android without any real issues.

Install it with:

```
npm install -g clipboard-cli
```

Then you can do:

```
echo foo | clipboard
```

If you want, you can alias to `cb` by putting the following in your `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, or `.zshrc`:

```
alias cb=clipboard
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's a safe `npm` package?

Comment: @Stas, I would hope so, it's made by Sindresorhus (https://github.com/sindresorhus), the most prolific node contributor. He's responsible for the Ava testing library, the xo linter, Yeoman, and countless other projects. He's also responsible for countless small libraries like this, that collectively put his code on nearly every JS-using website on the internet.

That's not to say he couldn't be compromised; just that the amount of eyes on his repos and his own reputation make it much less likely than most random npm repos.

Comment: Works with Yarn too: `yarn global add clipboard-cli`

Comment: Can't use it on a server through SSH because it needs a working UI (https://github.com/sindresorhus/clipboardy/issues/63). Useless without it as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Didn't work on FreeBSD with Wayland because it depends on xsel (which is X)

Answer (score 1119):

There are a wealth of clipboards you could be dealing with.  I expect you're probably a Linux user who wants to put stuff in the X Windows primary clipboard.  Usually, the clipboard you want to talk to has a utility that lets you talk to it.

In the case of X, there's `xclip` (and others). `xclip -selection c` will send data to the clipboard that works with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>  in most applications.

If you're on Mac OS X, there's `pbcopy`. E.g., `cat example.txt | pbcopy`

If you're in Linux terminal mode (no X) then look into `gpm` or [Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) which has a clipboard.  Try the Screen command `readreg`.

Under Windows 10+ or Cygwin, use `/dev/clipboard` or `clip`.

Comment: It is sad that GNU/Linux have no such a device as `/dev/clipboard`, and forces to install either xclip either gpm which is missing by default at least in Kubuntu *(I guess in most other distros too)*.

Comment: Under X11, there is also `xsel` which operates on the X selection by default. So you can `echo hello | xsel` or `xsel|wc` and so on without using a commmand-line switch.

Comment: @mike, `xsel -ib` works for me. `xsel` and `xclip` are implemented differently, `xclip` was what I was using but I'm working out of a chroot and `xclip` stopped copying data to the clipboard a few weeks ago, I switched to `xsel -ib` and haven't had any problems since.

Comment: At github page they suggest using ```clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub``` to copy SSH to clipboard. Reading this SO question I wonder how come is this possible? Is ```clip ``` a custom procedure that ships with git Bash?

Comment: any idea for wayland ?

Comment: @kr85 `clip.exe` is a builtin windows program which git-bash has access to, but it only works one-way (copying, not pasting). If you're using git-bash, then you're also on Windows.

Comment: bash *does* have a clipboard, though the documentation calls it a "kill ring". https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Killing-Commands.html

Comment: FYI, that's `readline`, not `bash` itself, but yes, it is accessible from bash, though only within the active process.

Comment: `clip` is bundled with windows since windows 7. also, since it's microsoft we're talking about, they obviously had to make a terrible program - with clip you can only write TO the clipboard, it can't help you read it.

Comment: `xclip` didn't work for me when putting it into a bash script (I'm on XFCE). `xsel` works. In my bash script, I use: `printf abc | xsel --input --clipboard`. Details: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316715/xclip-works-differently-in-interactive-and-non-interactive-shells

Comment: Running Debian in the WSL environment in Windows 10 Pro and no cigar guys, had to manually copy and paste.

Comment: Adding `-r` to xclip will remove the newline in the end. So `echo 'test string 456' | xclip -r -selection c` would work well in a single line.

Comment: doesn't seem to work with gnome from hyper terminal

Comment: @mh-cbon I believe xclip works on Wayland sessions too. I have been using `pass` (the CLI password manager) for a long time on Fedora Workstation, and it uses `xclip` to copy a password to the clipboard.

Comment: @crimson_king on wayland i now use wl-clipboard. It works like a charm https://github.com/bugaevc/wl-clipboard

Answer (score 361):

Make sure you are using `alias xclip="xclip -selection c"`
or else you won't be able to paste using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

Example:
After running `echo -n test | xclip`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> will paste `test`

Comment: How would one go about pasting it _without_ that command argument?

Comment: `xclip -selection clipboard -o`

Comment: since I go back and forth between osx and linux a lot I have the following in my dotfiles. `alias pbcopy="xclip -selection c"`  `alias pbpaste="xclip -selection clipboard -o"`  Hope that helps.

Comment: When I use this method it always adds in a newline character at the end of the copied text. Do you know of a way to disable or block that newline character?

Comment: @ApockofFork, `xclip` isnt adding a newline, `echo` is. Try `printf test | xclip -i -selection clipboard`. (`printf` doesnt add a newline unless you write `'test\n'`.)

Comment: Or use `echo -n` instead of `printf`.

Comment: To add a new alias: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias

Comment: Adding `-r` to xclip will remove the newline in the end. So `echo 'test string 456' | xclip -r -selection c`

Comment: "-r" argument does not seem to work on current ubuntu. To remove new line you may try this:
`uptime | tr -d '\n'  | xclip -selection c`

Answer (score 248):

## Install

```
# You can install xclip using `apt-get`
apt-get install xclip

# or `pacman`
pacman -S xclip

# or `dnf`
dnf install xclip
```

If you do not have access to `apt-get` nor `pacman`, nor `dnf`, the sources are available on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xclip/).

## Set-up

### Bash

In `~/.bash_aliases`, add:

```
alias setclip="xclip -selection c"
alias getclip="xclip -selection c -o"
```

*Do not forget to load your new configuration using `. ~/.bash_aliases` or by restarting your profile.*

### Fish

In `~/.config/fish/config.fish`, add:

```
abbr setclip "xclip -selection c"
abbr getclip "xclip -selection c -o"
```

*Do not forget to restart your fish instance by restarting your terminal for changes to apply.*

## Usage

You can now use `setclip` and `getclip`, e.g:

```
$ echo foo | setclip
$ getclip
foo
```

Answer (score 190):

On macOS, use the built-in [`pbcopy`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbcopy.1.html) and [`pbpaste`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbpaste.1.html) commands.

For example, if you run

```
cat ~/.bashrc | pbcopy
```

the contents of the `~/.bashrc` file will be available for pasting with the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> shortcut.

To save the current clipboard to a file, redirect the output [`pbpaste`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbpaste.1.html) to a file:

```
pbpaste > my_clipboard.txt
```

Comment: `pbcopy < my_clipboard.txt` can also be used for copying contents from a file.

Comment: Nice! I usually do `cat my_clipboard.txt | pbcopy` to copy the contents of a file to my clipboard, but `pbcopy < my_clipboard.txt` is way smoother.

Answer (score 55):

**xsel** on Debian/Ubuntu/Mint

```
# append to clipboard:
cat 'the file with content' | xsel -ab

# or type in the happy face :) and ...
echo 'the happy face :) and content' | xsel -ib

# show clipboard
xsel -ob

# Get more info:
man xsel
```

Install

```
sudo apt-get install xsel
```

Comment: How does this differ from `echo "foo" | xclip -selection c`?

Comment: There are some answers on this [Ask Ubuntu answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/705620/xclip-vs-xsel), but mainly `xsel` and `xclip` are equivalent in every way except that `xclip` can read/write files by name, but `xsel` requires shell redirection if you want to access a file.

Answer (score 43):

Try

[`xclip`](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/xclip)

```
xclip - command line interface to X selections (clipboard)
```

[man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip)

Answer (score 39):

On the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) (WSL) you can copy to the clipboard with *clip.exe*:

```
cat file | clip.exe
```

Keep in mind to use the `|` pipe command. And not a `>` command, since that will not work.

Answer (score 22):

Install the xcopy utility and when you're in the Terminal, input:

**Copy**

```
Thing_you_want_to_copy | xclip -selection c
```

**Paste**

```
myvariable=$(xclip -selection clipboard -o)
```

I noticed a lot of answers recommended *pbpaste* and *pbcopy*. If you're into those utilities, but for some reason they are not available in your repository, you can always make an alias for the xcopy commands and call them pbpaste and pbcopy.

```
alias pbcopy="xclip -selection c"
alias pbpaste="xclip -selection clipboard -o"
```

So then it would look like this:

```
Thing_you_want_to_copy | pbcopy
myvariable=$(pbpaste)
```

<sub>An answer located in one of the comments written by a user called doug work for me. Since I found it so helpful, I decided to restate in an answer.</sub>

Answer (score 14):

Here is a ready-to-use Bash script for reading the clipboard which works on multiple platforms.

Please edit the script here if you add functionality (e.g., more platforms).

```
#!/bin/bash
# WF 2013-10-04
#
# Multi-platform clipboard read access
#
# Supports
#   Mac OS X
#   Git shell / Cygwin (Windows)
#   Linux (e.g., Ubuntu)

#
# Display an error
#
error() {
  echo "error: $1" 1>&2
  exit 1
}

#
# getClipboard
#
function getClipboard() {
 os=`uname`
      case $os in
        # Git Bash  (Windows)
        MINGW32_NT-6.1)
          cat /dev/clipboard;;
        # Mac OS X
        Darwin*)
          pbpaste;;
        # Linux
        Linux*)
          # Works only for the X clipboard - a check that X is running might be due
          xclip -o;;
        *)
          error "unsupported os $os";;
      esac
}

tmp=/tmp/clipboard$$
getClipboard >$tmp
cat $tmp
# Comment out for debugging
rm $tmp
```

Answer (score 13):

For Mac only:

```
echo "Hello World" | pbcopy
pbpaste
```

These are located `/usr/bin/pbcopy` and `/usr/bin/pbpaste`.

Answer (score 11):

On Windows (with Cygwin) try
`cat /dev/clipboard` or `echo "foo" > /dev/clipboard` as mentioned in this article.

Comment: As user @maep mentioned in a separate comment, newer versions of Windows (I can only confirm for Win10) can simply pipe to `clip`. I'm using msysgit 1.9.5 and this worked.

Comment: `echo "foo" > /dev/clipboard` seems to destroy newlines completely (not a \r\n \n thing but completely gone)

Comment: broken link fix (couldn't edit): https://www.pgrs.net/2008/01/11/command-line-clipboard-access/

Comment: Yeah @user1529413,  seems to be a bit flaky too.  `printf " Hi \r\n there" > /dev/clipboard; sed 's/^\(.*\)/CLIP: "\1"/' /dev/clipboard` sometimes shows `CLIP: " HI "`, and sometimes doesn't show anything at all.  It's like it goes to sleep. :D

Answer (score 8):

I just searched the same stuff in my [KDE](https://kde.org/) environment.

Feel free to use `clipcopy` and `clippaste`.

**KDE:**

```sh
> echo "TEST CLIP FROM TERMINAL" | clipcopy
> clippaste
TEST CLIP FROM TERMINAL
```

Answer (score 7):

I have found a good reference: *[How to target multiple selections with xclip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69111/how-to-target-multiple-selections-with-xclip)*

In my case, I would like to paste content on the clipboard and also to see what is been pasted there, so I used also the `tee` command with a file descriptor:

```
echo "just a test" | tee >(xclip -i -selection clipboard)
```

`>()` is a form of process substitution. Bash replaces each with the path to a file descriptor which is connected to the standard input of the program within the parentheses.

The `tee`command forks your command allowing you to "pipe its content" and see the result on standard output "stdout".

You can also create aliases to get and write on the clipboard, allowing you to use "pbcopy" and "pbpaste" as if you where on Mac. In my case, as I use [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (`zsh`), I have this in my aliases file:

```
(( $+commands[xclip] )) && {
    alias pbpaste='xclip -i -selection clipboard -o'
    alias pbcopy='xclip -selection clipboard'
}
```

The `(( $+command[name] ))` in Z shell tests if the command "name" is installed on your system, and then both aliases are grouped with `{}`. The `&&` is a binary *AND*; if a then b, hence if you have xclip then the aliases will be set.

```
echo "another test" | tee >(pbcopy)
```

To get your clipboard content, just type:

```
pbpaste | "any-command-you-need-here"
```

Answer (score 7):

On [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol)), xcopy doesn't seem to work. Use [wl-clipboard](https://github.com/bugaevc/wl-clipboard) instead.

E.g., on [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29):

```
sudo dnf install wl-clipboard

tree | wl-copy

wl-paste > file
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a simple Python script that does just what you need:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

# Clipboard storage
clipboard_file = '/tmp/clipboard.tmp'

if(sys.stdin.isatty()): # Should write clipboard contents out to stdout
    with open(clipboard_file, 'r') as c:
        sys.stdout.write(c.read())
elif(sys.stdout.isatty()): # Should save stdin to clipboard
    with open(clipboard_file, 'w') as c:
        c.write(sys.stdin.read())
```

Save this as an executable somewhere in your path (I saved it to `/usr/local/bin/clip`. You can pipe in stuff to be saved to your clipboard...

```
echo "Hello World" | clip
```

And you can pipe what's in your clipboard to some other program...

```
clip | cowsay
 _____________
< Hello World >
 -------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

Running it by itself will simply output what's in the clipboard.

Comment: This works when you're on a single computer, but won't allow you to copy things between computers.

Comment: seems only  ` echo str > tmpfile` and  `cat tmpfile` , not clipboard operation. //same as @horta answers.

Comment: this doesn't seem to set clipboard variable, so I cannot paste the content in other application - it's not a real clipboard!

Comment: Didn't work on `git bash` terminal with windows `python` 3.10.7 running.  Too bad.  I tried `printf " Hi \r\n there" | pclip; pclip | sed 's/^\(.*\)$/CLIP: "\1"/'` and nothing came out.

Answer (score 5):

Copy and paste to clipboard in Windows (Cygwin):

See:

```
$ clip.exe -?

CLIP
Description:
    Redirects output of command line tools to the Windows clipboard.
    This text output can then be pasted into other programs.
Parameter List:
/?                  Displays this help message.
Examples:
DIR | CLIP          Places a copy of the current directory
                        listing into the Windows clipboard.
CLIP < README.TXT   Places a copy of the text from readme.txt
                        on to the Windows clipboard.
```

Also getclip (it can be used instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ins</kbd>!) and putclip (echo oaeuoa | putclip.exe to put it into clip) exist.

Comment: Can't put stuff into the clipboard though, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

```
  xsel -b
```

Does the job for X Window, and it is mostly already installed.
A look in the man page of [xsel](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xsel) is worth the effort.

Answer (score 5):

In Linux this works:

```
cat filename | xclip
```

Comment: But already covered by previous answers(?).

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes and no. When reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/4208191/11154841 and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/27456981/11154841, you think that you need to make an alias like `alias xclip="xclip -selection c"`. But xclip does not seem to need to have this alias, see also [How to pipe text from command line to the clipboard - Super User](https://superuser.com/a/124282/1192848) in 2010.

Answer (score 5):

pbcopy is built into OS X:

Copying the content of file *.bash_profile*:

```
cat ~/.bash_profile | pbcopy
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways. Some of the ways that have been mentioned include (I think) [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux), [Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen), [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29), [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs), and the shell. I don't know Emacs or Screen, so I'll go over the other three.

### Tmux

While not an X selection, tmux has a copy mode accessible via `prefix-[` (`prefix` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> by default). The buffer used for this mode is separate and exclusive to tmux, which opens up quite a few possibilities and makes it more versatile than the X selections in the right situations.

To exit this mode, hit <kbd>Q</kbd>; to navigate, use your Vim or Emacs binding (default = Vim), so `hjkl` for movement, `v/V/C-v` for character/line/block selection, etc. When you have your selection, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to copy and exit the mode.

To paste from this buffer, use `prefix-]`.

### Shell

Any installation of `X11` seems to come with two programs by default: `xclip` and `xsel` (kind of like how it also comes with both `startx` and `xinit`). Most of the other answers mention `xclip`, and I really like `xsel` for its brevity, so I'm going to cover `xsel`.

From [xsel(1x)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xsel):

> ### Input options \
>
> #### -a, --append \
>
> append standard input to the selection. Implies **-i**.
>
> #### -f, --follow \
>
> append to selection as standard input grows. Implies **-i**.
>
> #### -i, --input \
>
> read standard input into the selection.
>
> ### Output options \
>
> #### -o, --output \
>
> write the selection to standard output.
>
> ### Action options \
>
> #### -c, --clear \
>
> clear the selection. Overrides all input options.
>
> #### -d, --delete \
>
> Request that the current selection be deleted. This not only clears the selection, but also requests to the program in which the selection resides that the selected contents be deleted. Overrides all input options.
>
> ### Selection options \
>
> #### -p, --primary \
>
> operate on the PRIMARY selection (default).
>
> #### -s, --secondary \
>
> operate on the SECONDARY selection.
>
> #### -b, --clipboard \
>
> operate on the CLIPBOARD selection.

And that's about all you need to know. `p` (or nothing) for `PRIMARY`, `s` for `SECONDARY`, `b` for `CLIPBOARD`, `o` for output.

Example: say I want to copy the output of `foo` from a TTY and paste it to a webpage for a bug report. To do this, it would be ideal to copy to/from the TTY/X session. So the question becomes *how do I access the clipboard from the TTY?*

For this example, we'll assume the X session is on display `:1`.

```
$ foo -v
Error: not a real TTY
details:
blah blah @ 0x0000000040abeaf4
blah blah @ 0x0000000040abeaf8
blah blah @ 0x0000000040abeafc
blah blah @ 0x0000000040abeb00
...
$ foo -v | DISPLAY=:1 xsel -b # copies it into clipboard of display :1
```

Then I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> it into the form as per usual.

Now say that someone on the support site gives me a command to run to fix the problem. It's complicated and long.

```
$ DISPLAY=:1 xsel -bo
sudo foo --update --clear-cache --source-list="http://foo-software.com/repository/foo/debian/ubuntu/xenial/164914519191464/sources.txt"
$ $(DISPLAY=:1 xsel -bo)
Password for braden:
UPDATING %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 100.00%
Clearing cache...
Fetching sources...
Reticulating splines...
Watering trees...
Climbing mountains...
Looking advanced...
Done.
$ foo
Thank you for your order. A pizza should arrive at your house in the next 20 minutes. Your total is $6.99
```

*Pizza ordering* seems like a productive use of the command line.

...moving on.

### Vim

If compiled with `+clipboard` (This is important! Check your `vim --version`), Vim should have access to the X `PRIMARY` and `CLIPBOARD` selections. The two selections are accessible from the `*` and `+` registers, respectively, and may be written to and read from at your leisure the same as any other register.

For example:

```
:%y+    ; copy/yank (y) everything (%) into the CLIPBOARD selection (+)
"+p     ; select (") the CLIPBOARD selection (+) and paste/put it
ggVG"+y ; Alternative version of the first example
```

If your copy of Vim doesn't directly support access to X selections, though, it's not the end of the world. You can just use the `xsel` technique as described in the last section.

```
:r ! xsel -bo ; read  (r) from the stdout of (!) `xsel -bo`
:w ! xsel -b  ; write (w) to the stdin of    (!) `xsel -b`
```

Bind a couple key combos and you should be good.

Comment: Definitely always remember to use `DISPLAY=` when calling an X application from a non-X environment. X apps need the `DISPLAY` environment variable to figure out which server (or is there just one server handling multiple sessions?) they're talking to. Try `DISPLAY=:1 firefox` (or whatever your display ID may be; mine just happens to be `:1`) from a TTY, for example.

Comment: For me the choice in my environment was `:%y+` in VIM.

Comment: Xubuntu 22.04.3 LTS no `xsel` or `xclip` is installed by default.

Answer (score 3):

Yesterday I found myself with the question: *"How can I share the clipboard between different user sessions?"*. When switching between sessions with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>, in fact, you can't paste what you copied.

I came up with the following *quick & dirty* solution, based on a named pipe. It is surely quite bare and raw, but I found it functional:

```
user1@host:~$ mkfifo /tmp/sharedClip
```

then in the sending terminal

```
user1@host:~$ cat > /tmp/sharedClip
```

last, in the receiving terminal:

```
user2@host:~$ cat /tmp/sharedClip
```

Now, you type or paste anything in the first terminal, and (after hitting <kbd>Return</kbd>), it will appear immediately in the receiving terminal, from where you can copy and paste again anywhere you like.

Of course this doesn't just strictly take the content from user1's clipboard to make it available in user2's clipboard, but rather it requires an additional pair of Paste & Copy clicks.

Comment: Doesn't seem too surprising. Two different X servers = two different selection sets. However, you *could* set up a script that takes input/output via `xsel/xclip`. For example, one end listens to see if any of the selections changed, and then automatically pipes it (via the named FIFO) over to the other script, which is listening to one or more pipes, which inserts it into its own X selection. Copying text would thus automatically result in the same text appearing in the other X session's selection. And don't forget about `$DISPLAY`.

Answer (score 2):

A few Windows programs I wrote years ago. They allow you dump, push, append and print the clipboard. It works like this:

```
dumpclip | perl -pe "s/monkey/chimp/g;" | pushclip
```

It includes source code: [cmd_clip.zip](http://www.jeremyenglish.org/packs/cmd_clip.zip)

Comment: Link is dead.  Too bad.

Answer (score 2):

From this thread, there is an option which does not require installing any `gclip`/`xclip`/`xsel` third-party software.

A Perl script (since Perl is usually always installed)

```perl
use Win32::Clipboard;
print Win32::Clipboard::GetText();
```

Comment: How would I use this? Save script into PATH and pipe into it? I'm trying to write dropbox cli wrapper to copy sharing links, so I just need it to handle text.

Comment: @jena Example: https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Clipboard or https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=143637 or http://www.bribes.org/perl/docfr/win32clipboard.html.

Comment: Doesn't work with `git bash` (`cpan` is broken and won't download anything) or `MSYS2` (`cpan` did attempt it, but said that the OS isn't supported).

Comment: @Adrian True. For Windows (even from a Git bash session), I would call an executable (compiled in Go) which uses [win32 DLL calls to read Windows clipboard](https://github.com/atotto/clipboard/blob/1438b322bde482cc6decd8bc53dbe2eece57668b/clipboard_windows.go#L22-L28). That way, I can [copy/paste](https://github.com/atotto/clipboard#commands).

Answer (score 2):

The [Ruby oneliner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47069038/630752) inspired me to try with Python.

Say we want a command that indents whatever is in the clipboard with four spaces. It is perfect for sharing snippets on Stack Overflow.

```
$ pbpaste | python -c "import sys
 for line in sys.stdin:
   print(f'    {line}')" | pbcopy
```

That's not a typo. Python needs newlines to do a *for* loop. We want to alter the lines in one pass to avoid building up an extra array in memory.

If you don't mind building the extra array try:

```
$ pbpaste | python -c "import sys; print(''.join([f'    {l}' for l in sys.stdin]))" | pbcopy
```

but honestly awk is better for this than python. I defined this alias in my `~/.bashrc` file

```
alias indent="pbpaste | awk '{print \"    \"\$0}' | pbcopy"
```

Now when I run `indent`, whatever is in my clipboard is indented.

Comment: You can just drop the brackets and use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension. `''.join(f'    {l}' for l in sys.stdin)` -- also for most folks `python` will point to python2 on MacOS. So, you may want to specify `python3` instead.

Comment: What is "the Ruby oneliner"? What are you referring to? Another answer? Or something else? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61265818/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: @HarryMoreno : I usually just do the list comprehension one. Like my standard shell function to normalize `UTF8` back to `NFC` form, I use :::::::::: ::::::::: ::::::::::::::::::::: ::::::: :::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::  `python3 -c 'import sys; import unicodedata as __;\
 ___ = "";\
 [ print(__.normalize("NFC", _), end = ___) for _ in sys.stdin ]'` ::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::: those annoying backslashes represent a literal backslash  `'\'` followed by `\n`, since `python` loves complaining abt indentation, which makes it REALLY inconvenient to work w/ 4 shell 1-liners

Answer (score 1):

In macOS, use `pbpaste`.

For example:

Update the clipboard

```
pbpaste  | ruby -ne ' puts "\|" + $_.split( )[1..4].join("\|") ' | pbcopy
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to paste from the clipboard to a file without any tools except `echo`.

1. Escape single quotes in the text you want to paste: replace all occurrences of `'` with `'\''` and copy the result to clipboard.
2. Type `echo -n '`
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>
4. Type `' > filename.txt`
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Basically you're doing this:

`echo -n 'copied "text" with '\''single quotes'\'' escaped' > filename.txt`

It works even if the copied text has new lines.

Comment: Shift+Insert is accessing the clipboard

Answer (score 1):

For **mac** you can use this function which uses `pbcopy` and `pbpaste`, but a little easier:

Add this to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```sh
clp() {
  if [[ -z "$1" ]]
  then
    # No input - act as paste
    pbpaste;
  else
    # Input exists - act as copy
    echo "$1" | pbcopy;
  fi
}
```

To copy use `clp "Content"` and to paste use `clp`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using "Windows Terminal" to ssh into a Linux host, you can use the following little script to copy a file to the clipboard of the windows host:

```
# Clipfile
#  - Sends a file into the Windows Terminal clipboard
printf $'\e]52;c;%s\a' "$(base64 ${1:?})"
```

I'm not sure if this works with other terminal and console programs???

Thanks to @MrCalvin answer at: https://superuser.com/questions/1705770/copy-data-from-linux-console-to-windowshost-clipboard-using-windows-terminal?newreg=8ad2f39ec3f54a659b0c9e295540bbf1

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me and run on a Linux server without root privileges and there isn't any [xclip](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip) or [GPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPM_(software)) you could workaround this issue by just using a temporary file. For example:

```
$ echo "Hello, World!" > ~/clip
$ echo `cat ~/clip`
Hello, World!
```

Comment: I don't see how a lack of root privileges factors into this.

Comment: @BradenBest Lack of root privileges means I couldn't install things.

Comment: But what would you be installing? X? On a server? Unless you're hosting some weird X forwarding service, I can't see why you would ever want to do that.

Comment: @BradenBest Not sure. Whatever program or service would allow me to perform a copy paste.

Comment: Well, if you're using any of the `X selections` (which is necessarily implied by "clipboard" and any mentions of xclip/xsel), you need an active X session (and thus an X server) so that you can access the selection in the first place. To see what I mean, try running `DISPLAY="" xsel` on your local machine. It will exit on an error, being unable to find session `""`, and no interaction with any X selection will be made. That's why I initially said that I don't see how root privileges factor into this: root or no root, you're not likely to find an X selection useful in a server environment.

Answer (score 0):

This function will test what clipboard exists and use it.

To verify copy paste into your shell, and then call the function `clippaste`:

```
clippaste () {
    if [[ $OSTYPE == darwin* ]]
    then
            pbpaste
    elif [[ $OSTYPE == cygwin* ]]
    then
            cat /dev/clipboard
    else
            if command -v xclip &> /dev/null
            then
                    xclip -out -selection clipboard
            elif command -v xsel
            then
                    xsel --clipboard --output
            else
                    print "clipcopy: Platform $OSTYPE not supported or xclip/xsel not installed" >&2
                    return 1
            fi
    fi
}
```