# How to capture cURL output to a file?

Tags: batch-file, curl

I have a text document that contains a bunch of URLs in this format:

```
URL = "sitehere.com"
```

What I'm looking to do is to run `curl -K myfile.txt`, and get the output of the response cURL returns, into a file.

How can I do this?

Comment: `curl http://{one,two}.example.com -o "file_#1.txt"` https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Answer (score 979, accepted):

```
curl -K myconfig.txt -o output.txt
```

Writes the *first* output received in the file you specify (overwrites if an old one exists).

```
curl -K myconfig.txt >> output.txt
```

Appends all output you receive to the specified file.

**Note: The -K is optional.**

If you are posting to a URL like https://example.org/?foo=1&baz=4
then you need to put double quotes around the URL:

```bash
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" --data-binary "@/home/path/file.xyz" "https://xample.org:8080/v1/?filename=file.xyz&food=1&z=bee" >out.txt 2>err.txt
```

Comment: Sorry maybe I need to clarify - the doc with all my URL's in the format about is called myfile.txt so I do curl -K myfile.txt and it runs though each one but I don't get the output into any file.

Comment: I use the redirect for my command lines: `curl url > destfile.x`

Comment: When I do either of these the output still displays in the terminal, not in the file

Comment: @kris you probably have an ampersand in the url.  put the url in double quotes and then try

Comment: It works without the -K. With it, I get "No URL specified."

Comment: thank you. i was thinking about using wget and then find the solution to ignore the ssl like curl. turned out that we need to only using -o like wget instead of -k like curl :)

Comment: This only captures the last line, not the whole `curl` output.

Answer (score 291):

For a single file you can use `-O` instead of `-o filename` to use the last segment of the URL path as the filename. Example:

```
curl http://example.com/folder/big-file.iso -O
```

will save the results to a new file named **big-file.iso** in the current folder. In this way it works similar to [wget](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/wget.1.html) but allows you to specify other [curl options](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/curl.1.html) that are not available when using wget.

Comment: for multiple files use `--remote-name-all` https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265819/171025

Comment: To follow redirect, add `-L` option.

Comment: Another addition for qwr's comment: the argument need to be put before the URLs like `curl --remote-name-all https://example.tld/resource{1,2,3}`. See: https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--remote-name-all

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, this nice and useful`-O` option. Thanks!

Comment: `-O` - that's a "letter Oooh" as in "Output" (not a zero)

Answer (score 83):

There are several options to make curl output to a file

```bash
# saves it to myfile.txt
curl http://www.example.com/data.txt -o myfile.txt

# The #1 will get substituted with the url, so the filename contains the url
curl http://www.example.com/data.txt -o "file_#1.txt" 

# saves to data.txt, the filename extracted from the URL
curl http://www.example.com/data.txt -O 

# saves to filename determined by the Content-Disposition header sent by the server.
curl http://www.example.com/data.txt -O -J
```

Answer (score 19):

Either `curl` or `wget` can be used in this case. All 3 of these commands do the same thing, downloading the file at http://path/to/file.txt and saving it locally into "my_file.txt".

*Note that in all commands below, I also recommend using the `-L` or `--location` option with `curl` in order to follow HTML 302 redirects to the new location of the file, if it has moved. `wget` requires no additional options to do this, as it does this automatically.*

```bash
# save the file locally as my_file.txt

wget http://path/to/file.txt -O my_file.txt  # my favorite--it has a progress bar
curl -L http://path/to/file.txt -o my_file.txt
curl -L http://path/to/file.txt > my_file.txt
```

Alternatively, to save the file as the same name locally as it is remotely, use either `wget` by itself, or `curl` with `-O` or `--remote-name`:

```bash
# save the file locally as file.txt

wget http://path/to/file.txt
curl -LO http://path/to/file.txt
curl -L --remote-name http://path/to/file.txt
```

*Notice that the `-O` in all of the commands above is the capital letter "O".*

The nice thing about the `wget` command is it shows a nice progress bar.

You can prove the files downloaded by each of the sets of 3 techniques above are exactly identical by comparing their sha512 hashes. Running `sha512sum my_file.txt` after running each of the commands above, and comparing the results, reveals all 3 files to have the exact same sha hashes (sha sums), meaning the files are exactly identical, byte-for-byte.

### References

1. I learned about the `-L` option with `curl` here: [Is there a way to follow redirects with command line cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18474746/4561887)

<sub>See also: [`wget` command to download a file and save as a different filename](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69411410/4561887)</sub>

Answer (score 7):

For those of you want to copy the cURL output in the clipboard instead of outputting to a file, you can use `pbcopy` by using the pipe `|` after the cURL command.

Example: `curl https://www.google.com/robots.txt | pbcopy`. This will copy all the content from the given URL to your clipboard.

Linux version: `curl https://www.google.com/robots.txt | xclip`

Windows version: `curl https://www.google.com/robots.txt | clip`

Comment: pbcopy is only available on MacOS.  However `xclip` can be used in it's place for [Linux see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130968/how-can-i-copy-the-output-of-a-command-directly-into-my-clipboard).  However I would in most cases prefer `curl http://example.com -o example_com.html & cat example_com.html | pbcopy`  So you wouldn't  need to curl again if you accidently clear your clipboard.

Comment: Also this should be used with caution if you're unsure of the size of the payload.  For example you probably wouldn't want to paste this into a text editor, but opening it in vim no problem.
`curl http://www.textfiles.com/etext/FICTION/fielding-history-243.txt | pbcopy` maybe don't try this!

Answer (score 6):

You need to add quotation marks between "URL" -o "file_output" otherwise, curl doesn't recognize the URL or the text file name.

**Format**

```bash
curl "url" -o filename
```

**Example**

```bash
curl "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark" -o output_file.txt
```

**Example_2**

```bash
curl "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark" > output_file.txt
```

**Just make sure to add quotation marks.**

Comment: Thank you.  I was looking around for a while before I found your comment.  Now I don't have to watch 59Mb of text scroll up the screen to nowhere any more :-)

Answer (score 4):

Use `--trace-ascii output.txt` to output the curl details to the file `output.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, the man page mentions that this also outputs the "descriptive information" that `-vv` displays (SSL info, HTTP verb, headers, ...), which I wanted to store. None of the other answers write that to a file.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store your output into your desktop, follow the below command using post command in git bash.It worked for me.

```bash
curl https://localhost:8080
    --request POST 
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" 
    -o "C:\Desktop\test.json"
```

Answer (score 1):

A tad bit late, but I think the OP was looking for something like:

```
curl -K myfile.txt --trace-ascii output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

My favorite is lwp-download, which can be found here: https://metacpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/view/bin/lwp-download

You can use it like this:

```
lwp-download http://www.perl.com/CPAN/src/latest.tar.gz
```

This will store the file as "latest.tar.gz" in your current directory, so no further option is needed.

Answer (score -2):

Writes the first output received in the file you specify (overwrites if an old one exists).

```
curl -K myconfig.txt >> output.txt
```

Comment: The `>>` appends, it does not overwrite. If you would like to overwrite, use a single `>`