# How to download .zip file using PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have my website in `http://domain1.com` and I want to download some `.zip` file from another domain `http://domain2.com/uploads/data.zip` but not getting download and showing 302 moved temporary error. I am using cURL code.

```php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.domain2.com');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($response));  
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary');  
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=my.zip");
//readfile($response);
header("Location:$response");
```

Comment: where is curl code??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to follow redirects with command line cURL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474690/is-there-a-way-to-follow-redirects-with-command-line-curl)

Answer (score 1):

Just create one php file on project root. like "test.php"

now add below code on "test.php" file.

```
file_put_contents("zipname.zip", fopen("http://domain2.com/uploads/data.zip", 'r'));
```

This is fastest and easy way to download file using php.

for more detail below article

https://thecodingstuff.com/php-download-archive-file-from-url/