# Curl: 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: curl, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am trying to write a script to download a file using curl command line.

According to [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50347440/curl-302-moved-temporarily), I should be able to follow a 301 using the `-L` flag. Here is what I am seeing on my Ubuntu 22.04.1 system:

```
$ curl -s -I "https://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/2023c" | head -1
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
```

So let's give it a try:

```
$ curl -s -L "https://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/2023c/source/docbook/part15/part15.xml" | head -5 | tail -1
<title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>
```

However from my google chrome the link `https://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/2023c` redirects to `https://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current` ([hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/how-to-redirect-one-html-page-to-another-on-load)).

Let's give it a try:

```
$ curl -s -O "https://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/source/docbook/part15/part15.xml"
```

Gives the expected result:

```
$ head -4 part15.xml | tail -1
  <subtitle>DICOM PS3.15 2023c - Security and System Management Profiles</subtitle>
```

What am I missing here to have a working script to download any version:

```
$ VERSION=2023c curl "https://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/${VERSION}/source/docbook/part15/part15.xml"
```

---

For reference:

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.81.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.81.0 OpenSSL/3.0.2 zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.4.8 libidn2/2.3.2 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.3.2) libssh/0.9.6/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.43.0 librtmp/2.3 OpenLDAP/2.5.13
Release-Date: 2022-01-05
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd
```

Answer (score 0):

If you you are trying the same URL https://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/2023b when using the -L option you will see that curl will follow the redirect like the browser. When you are using the URL https://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/source/docbook/part15/part15.xml in you're browser you will also see the same behaviour like using curl: You will get a HTTP 404.