# How to append the wget downloaded file?

Tags: linux, cron, webserver, wget

I am running wget through cronjob for executing some script in scheduled manner. Everytime the output is downloaded and saved as new file. I want to append the output to same file. How can I do that?

I am talking about the downloaded content from the URL but not the log of the execution.

Comment: Might be better in this case use **curl**  check out this _example_ [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735051/curl-and-capturing-output-to-a-file)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can do it using the following command:

```
   wget <URL> -O ->> <FILE_NAME>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked. Not sure why its not selected as the correct answer

Comment: This solution may be not binary-safe. At least in Windows 10, it adds `0x0D` before every `0x0A` in downloaded content.

Comment: Not working with wget version 1.8.2 on Windows 10, overwrites output file

Comment: This is very strange, because `echo 1 >> out.txt` appends file and `wget http://some.com -O - 2>> out.txt` also appends file (not with downloaded file, but with download log). It looks like downloaded file contains some symbol, which prevents append function altogether. A working workaround is `wget http://some.com -O ->out.txt` and then `type out.txt >> log.txt`

Answer (score 0):

My first approach now would be to download it to a file, add the content of the new downloaded file to the previously downloaded file and delete it.