# Save large JSON to text straight from REST API response stream in Java

Tags: java, json, rest, inputstream

What is the best way to save a large JSON from a REST API call to a text file?  I currently use Postman in Chrome to test the API and sometimes it makes Chrome un-responsive due large JSON output.  I would like to write some Java codes to save the large JSON to a text file.  Is there a way to stream the REST output straight to text input stream so that it wouldn't take too much memory at run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest that you use [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html).

An example usage is found here : [Capture Curl Output to a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735051/curl-and-capturing-output-to-a-file)

It should be more efficient than buffering the entire output.