# Log the return of curl which runs in a cron job

Tags: php, linux, curl, cron

I've page "test.php" that runs a PHP script and return datetime / some results ... this page I call in a cron job, it runs successfully but I want to log the returned results in one file

I tried this ... cron_log.log was empty

```
wget -q -O - http://****/test.php >> /home/****/logs/cron_log/cron_log.log
```

I tried this ... but the cron_log.log contained date about the job execution, not the the response returned from the test.php

```
curl http://****/test.php > /home/****/logs/cron_log/cron_log.log 2>&1
```

Please can you help me in logging the returned results from curl?

**P.S.** I'm using a cPanel and I've access to the WHM

**Update** I need to append responses in the log file, so I can follow up the execution log of the cron job, this command (curl -k) truncates the log file, however I need to append returns on it.

```
curl -K http://****/test.php >> /home/****/logs/cron_log/cron_log.log
```

Comment: what is the return of test.php script ?

Comment: @Fky The script returns the current date/time and a counter ...all are concatenated in one string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture Curl Output to a File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735051/capture-curl-output-to-a-file)

Comment: @Fky, thank you but my question is different, please check the updates

Comment: i edited my answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
curl http://****/test.php >> /home/****/logs/cron_log/cron_log.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Thank you, this works but without "2>&1" as this part adds the execution summary to the response.

Comment: @DoaaMagdy you're welcome and yes , just remove it if don't want it :)