# How to install ripgrep on Windows?

Tags: windows, ripgrep

How do I install [ripgrep (`rg`)](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) on Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had to start developing on Windows again recently, and have had a hard time figuring this out.

So, here's what I've come up with:

*Tested in Windows 10 Pro and Windows 11 Pro.*

First, install [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/).

Then, open up the Git Bash terminal which comes with it. You should run all commands below in Git Bash unless stated otherwise.

### The super-short, quick answer:

Open Git Bash as an admin, and run:

```bash
# install ripgrep
choco install ripgrep
# verify it is now installed
rg --version
```

Other, non-admin options, and more details, are below:

### [More versatile, and does *not* require admin privileges] Option 1: how to *manually* install ripgrep (or any executable, for that matter) on Windows

This manual process is pretty much the same on Linux *or* Windows (except that Git for Windows is needed only on Windows), and can be used for *any* executable file or script.

Go to the [ripgrep releases page here](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/releases), and find the URL of the executable you want from the latest release. For 64-bit Windows, use either the GNU-compiled version (`ripgrep-13.0.0-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu.zip`), *or* the MSVC-compiled version (`ripgrep-13.0.0-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.zip`). I tested both and they both run fine. Note that the GNU-compiled `rg.exe` file is larger at around 38.2 MB, however, and the MSVC-compiled `rg.exe` is about 4.42 MB. I don't know why there is such a huge difference but I'm guessing it's because the MSVSC-compiled version is relying more on existing Windows dynamic libraries already available in the system.

In the instructions below, I used `ripgrep-13.0.0-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.zip`. Adapt the instructions accordingly if you use a different file.

```bash
# download the latest 64-bit Windows release file of your choosing (GNU or
# MSVC)
curl -LO https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/releases/download/13.0.0/ripgrep-13.0.0-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.zip
# unzip it
unzip ripgrep-13.0.0-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.zip

# create a ~/bin dir to store it
mkdir -p ~/bin 

# copy rg.exe into ~/bin
cd ripgrep-13.0.0-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
cp -i rg.exe ~/bin/
```

Now, create and edit your `~/.bashrc` file:

```bash
# Create `~/.bashrc` if it doesn't exist, or just update the access and
# modification time of the file if it does.
touch ~/.bashrc
# Open the file in your editor of choice. Examples:
notepad ~/.bashrc  # in Notepad
nano ~/.bashrc     # in Nano
subl ~/.bashrc     # in Sublime Text
code ~/.bashrc     # in Microsoft Visual Studio Code (MS VSCode)
```

Add this to the bottom of the `~/.bashrc` file you just opened (this is borrowed from Ubuntu's default `~/.profile` file, which I've put online [here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/etc/skel/.profile)):

```bash
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Finally, close and reopen all Git Bash terminals, *or* run this in all of them that are open:

```bash
# re-source your ~/.bashrc file to update your PATH
. ~/.bashrc
```

Now test to see that `rg` (ripgrep) works:

```bash
# check the version number
rg --version
```

My run and output is:

```bash
$ rg --version
ripgrep 13.0.0 (rev af6b6c543b)
-SIMD -AVX (compiled)
+SIMD +AVX (runtime)
```

### [Easier, but requires admin privileges] Option 2: how to install ripgrep (or other programs) via a package manager such as `choco` in Windows

##### Quick summary:

Press your <kbd>Windows</kbd> key --> type in "Git Bash" --> right-click your Git Bash shortcut --> click "Run as administrator". In this Git Bash window running as administrator, run the following commands:

```bash
# Install ripgrep in Windows.
# See: https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep#installation. Apparently my
# computer already has `choco` installed on it. 
choco install ripgrep
# - then follow the on-screen instructions, typing `y` for "yes", 
#   or `a` for "yes to all", when needed

# verify that ripgrep is installed; I see:
#       
#       ripgrep 13.0.0 (rev af6b6c543b)
#       -SIMD -AVX (compiled)
#       +SIMD +AVX (runtime)
#       
rg --version
```

While you're at it, you might as well install [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#windows) and [`bat`](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat#on-windows) too, since my `rgf2.sh` script (see: [here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/ripgrep_replace) and the installation instructions at the top of `rgf.sh`) requires both of those:

```bash
choco install fzf  # install fuzzy-finder
choco install bat  # install colored `cat` ("cat with wings")
```

Close the Git Bash admin window when done, and go back to using a non-admin Git Bash window.

##### Details

I am very accustomed to using `apt` or `snap` to install programs in Linux Ubuntu.

It turns out that there are 3 popular package managers in Windows too:

1. [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/): `choco install ripgrep`

   1. Very popular.
   2. It has some paid versions, but there is also a free (as in freedom) and open source, and no-cost, version for both individuals and companies/organizations as well. See: https://chocolatey.org/pricing.

      1. Looking in my directory at `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\LICENSE.txt`, I see that the open source license they use is the [Apache License, Version 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0), which I believe is a very non-restrictive (generous) license.
2. [Scoop](https://scoop.sh/): `scoop install ripgrep`
3. [Winget](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli) (see also [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/)): `winget install BurntSushi.ripgrep.MSVC`

   1. This is an official, Microsoft-supported app.

In Git Bash, check to see if you already have these tools installed. I already had `choco` and `winget` installed. I'm not sure why or how I already had them installed, but maybe they came with Windows, or with Git for Windows. See if they are installed on your system:

```bash
choco --version   # I see `1.3.0`
scoop --version   # I see: `bash: scoop: command not found`
winget --version  # I see: `v1.5.1572`
```

Let's use Chocolatey to install `ripgrep`, since [I've read](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/u80x1v/winget_vs_chocolatey_vs_scoop/) it may be the most popular and have the most programs on it.

1. Install it
   See: https://chocolatey.org/install.

   Run this in your Power Shell *only if you do not already have `choco` installed*:

   ```bash
   Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
   ```
2. Then, use it:

   Open up Git Bash as an administrator, and run:

   ```bash
   choco install ripgrep
   rg --version  # check the version to see if it installed correctly
   ```
3. Close the Git Bash admin window when done, and go back to using a non-admin Git Bash window.

### References

1. I first discovered the 3 main Windows package managers, Chocolatey, Scoop, and Winget [here](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep#installation) and [here](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/tree/master#windows).
2. [My own answer on how to use `curl`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69411327/4561887) (the `-L` part of my `curl` usage above is required, as GitHub had an HTML 302 redirect for the download link of the `ripgrep` release)