# Error: Can't open display: (null) when using Xclip to copy ssh public key

Tags: linux, ssh

I’m following in [Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#platform-linux), it says

> `sudo apt-get install xclip`

Downloads and installs xclip. If you don't have `apt-get`, you might need to use another installer (like `yum`)

> `xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Copies the contents of the id_rsa.pub file to your clipboard

But after I run`xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` I get `Error: Can't open display: (null)`
What is the problem? I googled around but found nothing about it

Comment: What does `echo $DISPLAY` say?

Comment: nothing. I'm running this command on a server via ssh

Answer (score 170, accepted):

`DISPLAY=:0 xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` didn't work for me (`ubuntu 14.04`), but you can use :

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

to get your public key

Comment: This should be the number 1 answer for anyone who is trying to copy file contents via ssh

Comment: Except when you're trying to copy a long file.

Comment: @dval, I don't agree it shall be number 1 answer, because the question mentions `xclip` usage not just displaying SSH key in a bash with `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. However, this helps to solve the problem, because you can copy the value when it's displayed.

Comment: what?! how this can solve the problem of xclip not functioning?

Comment: Actually, this answer is extremely misleading.

Comment: Answer -1. I found that this helped: https://madebynathan.com/2011/10/04/a-nicer-way-to-use-xclip/

It's a function and handy aliases for your .bash_profile

`# Copy contents of a file`
`function cbf() { cat "$1" | cb; }`
`# Copy SSH public key`
`alias cbssh="cbf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"`
`# Copy current working directory`
`alias cbwd="pwd | cb"`
`# Copy most recent command in bash history`
`alias cbhs="cat $HISTFILE | tail -n 1 | cb"`

Comment: This answer is changing the question.

Comment: This answer does NOT help when, for example, copying a pub key (it'll multiline copy it)

Comment: This solves the specific problem by working around the actual question, which is about xclip. It could be a comment, or part of the answer, but not the whole answer. I don't know why it was accepted.

Comment: Absolutely a bad answer. this is copy how to copy terminal content without using a mouse & keyboard as soon as the command is sent

Answer (score 138):

Based on the date of this question the original poster wouldn't have been using [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). But if you are, and you get the same error, the following alternative works:

```
clip.exe < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Thanks to [this page](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-yank) for pointing out Windows' clip.exe (and you have to type the ".exe") can be run from the bash shell.

Comment: you can also use pipes `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | clip.ese` just works

Comment: @chriz I think you mean "exe" not "ese"?

Comment: oh yeah, sorry that was just a typo, it's `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | clip.exe`.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Super! I was having this issue on Linux Subsystem under Windows. It works fine now.

Comment: how do you paste it?!?

Comment: @Moytaba CONTROL SHIFT V.

Comment: You can also add an alias clip=clip.exe.

Comment: Using Ubuntu over here installed from the Windows Store on a Windows 10 PC. This answer helped (ie using clip.exe instead of simple clip)

Comment: and for those who preferred a single command on all platforms: add this to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` : `alias pbcopy="clip.exe"`. 

and thanks to @chriz for pointing out pipe `|` works just fine.

Comment: The documentation found at `CLIP.EXE /?` states that it is only for copying. How do you paste so you can pipe the contents of the clipboard into other commands? I'd like to be able to casually juggle large, transient chunks of text around in one-liners. For example, something close to `xclip -o | xmllint --format - | vim -` (if that’s right) with an arbitrary website’s source.

Answer (score 71):

This was [too good of an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/305681) not to post it here. It's from [Gilles](https://askubuntu.com/users/1059/gilles), an *askubuntu* fellow:

> The clipboard is provided by the [X
> server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_server). It doesn't matter
> whether the server is headless or not, what matters is that your local
> graphical session is available to programs running on the remote
> machine. Thanks to X's network-transparent design, this is possible.
>
> I assume that you're connecting to the remote server with SSH from a
> machine running Linux. Make sure that X11 forwarding is enabled both
> in the client configuration and in the server configuration. In the
> client configuration, you need to have the line `ForwardX11 yes` in
> `~/.ssh/config` to have it on by default, or pass the option `-X` to
> the `ssh` command just for that session. In the server configuration,
> you need to have the line `X11Forwarding yes` in
> `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (it is present by default on Ubuntu).
>
> To check whether X11 forwarding is enabled, look at the value of the
> `DISPLAY` environment variable: `echo $DISPLAY`. You should see a
> value like `localhost:10` (applications running on the remote machine
> are told to connect to a display running on the same machine, but that
> display connection is in fact forwarded by SSH to your client-side
> display). Note that if `DISPLAY` isn't set, it's no use setting it
> manually: the environment variable is always set correctly if the
> forwarding is in place. If you need to diagnose SSH connection issues,
> pass the option `-vvv` to `ssh` to get a detailed trace of what's
> happening.
>
> If you're connecting through some other means, you may or may not be
> able to achieve X11 forwarding. If your client is running Windows,
> [PuTTY](http://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-x11)
> supports X11 forwarding; you'll have to run an X server on the Windows
> machine such as [Xming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/).
>
> By **[Gilles](https://askubuntu.com/users/1059/gilles)** from askubuntu

Comment: This isn't proper etiquette, but sheesh that is a phenomenal answer 

Answer (score 38):

In case you are trying to use xclip on remote host just add -X to your ssh command

```
ssh user@host -X
```

More detailed information can be found here : https://askubuntu.com/a/305681

Comment: For some reason I still had issue like `X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)`, until I found [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=609393#p609393) and this `ssh user@host -Y` worked for me. Make sure `ForwardX11 yes` in local and `X11Forwarding yes` in server.

Answer (score 20):

The following is also working for me:

```
ssh <user>@<host>  "cat <filepath>"|pbcopy
```

Comment: works also using a pem file: ssh -i /path/myapp.pem   <user>@<host> "cat <filepath>" | pbcopy

Comment: I thought pbcopy was a mac thing, not linux

Comment: That's a mac specific

Answer (score 13):

Try this and it will work like a charm. I was having the same error but this approach did the trick for me:

```
ssh USER@REMOTE "cat file"|xclip -i
```

Comment: Very good idea! It does work indeed, even if $DISPLAY is not set

Comment: If you're on a Mac, you can replace `xclip -i` with `pbcopy`

Answer (score 10):

Have read the documentation you've linked. That's totally silly! `xclip` is just a clipboard. You'll find other ways to copy paste the key... (I'm sure)

---

If you aren't working from inside a graphical X session you need to pass the `$DISPLAY` environment var to the command. Run it like this:

```
DISPLAY=:0 xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Of course `:0` depends on the display you are using. If you have a typical desktop machine it is likely that it is `:0`

Comment: I get `Error: Can't open display: :0`. By the way, I'm accessing a VPS through Git Bash. VPS is ubuntu, local machine is windows7

Comment: I think so. But I'm not familiar with ubuntu. Could you give me some advice?

Comment: Lol, I'm not payed at all. I use cat intead, but need to fomrat it manually

Comment: I have same issue with @cqcn1991

Comment: Suggestions: (1) Use the right mouse buttong to copy / paste it or (2) save to a file and scp that file to your local machine

Comment: @cqcn1991 Did you ever figure out how to use xclip or xsel when accessing a remote server via Git Bash on Windows? I'm getting `Error: Can't open display: (null)`. Thanks!

Comment: @cqcn1991 I've asked a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60117294/470749

Comment: Using `DISPLAY=:0 xclip` also works to clear the clipboard from a job.  In my case, I'm using `at` to clear the clipboard two minutes after copying.

Answer (score 1):

add by user root this command :
ssh user_to_acces@hostName -X

user_to_acces = user
hostName = hostname machine