# Copy code from IPython without leading triple dots

Tags: python, ipython, qtconsole

I'm using IPython Qt Console and when I copy code FROM Ipython it comes out like that:

```
    class notathing(object):
        ...:
        ...:     def __init__(self):
        ...:         pass
        ...:
```

Is there any way to copy them without those leading triple dots and doublecolon?

P.S. I tried both `Copy` and `Copy Raw Text` in context menu and it's still the same. OS: Debian Linux 7.2 (KDE).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This QTconsole copy regression has been fixed, see https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/3206 - I can confirm that the desired behavior is again present in the QtConsole in the Canopy 1.2 GUI and, I suspect, in the ipython egg installable by free users from the Enthought egg repo.

Answer (score 64):

How about using `%hist n` to print line `n` (or a range of lines) without prompts (including line continuations), and doing your copy from that?  (Simply scrolling back to that line is nearly as good).

```
In [1]: def foo():
   ...:     return 1+2
   ...: 

In [6]: %history 1
def foo():
    return 1+2
```

Comment: This is the way.

Comment: Magical!
`%hist` without any argument will print everything

Answer (score 7):

One of the cool features of `ipython` is [session logging](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.1.0/interactive/reference.html#session-logging-and-restoring). If you enable it, the code you input in your session is logged to a file.  It's very useful, I use it all the time.

To make things even niftier for me, I have a shell alias `ipy_log_cat`, which prints the entire file. You can do something like: `ipy_log_cat | tail` to get the most recent input lines. (this is also useful for `grep`ing session history, etc.). You can also save a few keyboard/mouse strokes by piping it into [`xclip`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130968/how-can-i-copy-the-output-of-a-command-directly-into-my-clipboard)!

Answer (score 2):

This may be too roundabout for you, but you could use the %save magic function to save the lines in question and then copy them from the save file.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to keep an open gvim window for this kind of things. Paste your class definition as is and then do something like:

```
:%s/^.*\.://
```