# How can I get cd | cbpaste to actually cd?

Tags: bash, pipe, copy-paste, cd

I surveyed SO and couldn't find this specific question. I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130968/how-can-i-copy-the-output-of-a-command-directly-into-my-clipboard/5130969#5130969), but that is for Linux. I am on OSx 10.7.5. Furthermore, I have the exact problem using xclip, and I would prefer to use cbcopy/cbpaste because when I run those, X11 doesn't open. However, if someone manages to find one, then ***kudos to you!***

I know how to pipe a command to copy using cbcopy. I know how to just paste. I assumed that I would be able to `cd | cbpaste`, but you know what happens when you assume...

Basically, I copy the pwd of one window:

```
$ pwd | cbcopy
/User/Name/dir/dir/dir/pwd
```

and then attempt to cd into it in another:

```
$ pwd
/User/Name
$ cd | cbpaste
/User/Name/dir/dir/dir/[pwd of the other window, because that's where I copied from]
$ pwd
/User/Name
```

And I haven't gone anywhere. It only spits out the clipboard.

The more I look at this, the more my `cd | cbpaste` makes no sense (the cd becomes invalid because I'm not actually telling it where to cd), but I figure there's gotta be a way to do what I'm trying to do and I just haven't found it on Google/SO.

I also have the same problem when I do this in the same window (i.e., I tested it by copying the pwd, cd to the root, and trying it again), which makes me think that my syntax is just wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piping over `cbpaste` to `cd` won't do anything except take you back to your home directory, since `cd` without any options does that. You need to put `cbpaste` inside an environment variable with `$(cbpaste)`:

```
$ pwd | cbcopy    [this works to copy the pwd]
$ cd              [this takes you to the home directory]
$ cd $(cbpaste)   [this takes you to the variable's 
                   value, which is the directory you copied]
```

Comment: Home directory, not root directory.