# write octave/matlab output to clipboard

Tags: windows, matlab, clipboard, octave

iam looking for a way to get the output of an octave statement to the windows clipboard.

iam not searching a way to just manually copy/paste text from the cmd window (i know how this would work). iam also not looking for getting the whole output of a complete octave session which could be gotten by launching octave with a script to execute and piping all output to some clip.exe.
i want to capture the output from some single statement that will be executed from octave promt or some function or script.

Would be great if someone has some advice.

Edit:
from a comment i learned about the clipboard command of matlab that is unfortunally not implemented yet in octave.
maybe any other ideas involving fancy `system()` calls?

Comment: It won't get much easier than this: http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/clipboard.html

Comment: `clipboard` is not available in octave

Comment: thanks. at least i now know the theoretical way how to do this. unfortunally Daniel is right. I wonder why the clipboard command does not came up with my google searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, apparently it's not *too* difficult to implement something fairly similar to Matlab - after a few minutes of fiddling around, behold my new `clipboard.m`:

```
function clipboard(data)
if ~ischar(data)
    data = mat2str(data);
end
data = regexprep(data, '\\','\\\\');
data = regexprep(data, '%','%%');
f = tempname;
h = fopen(f, 'w');
fprintf(h, data);
fclose(h);
system(['clip.exe < ' f]);
delete(f);
end
```

Comment: Two remarks: 

1. for linux, install xclip and use this `system()` call: `system(['cat ' f ' | xclip -selection clipboard']);`
2. you might want to use `num2str()` instead of `mat2str()` to get rid of the surrounding square brackets

(stack overflow reviewers think it's more appropriate to tease apart the code, I wanted to add them directly as comments in the code snippet above from @Notlikethat; sorry for that little mess, in addition because comments don't allow for nice formatting :/ )

Comment: replacing the two `regexprep` lines with 

`data = regexprep(data, " ","\t"); # replace spaces for tabs` &  `data = regexprep(data, ';','\n'); # replace ';' for newline` makes the export paste "nicely" into excel

Answer (score 2):

You could always call something like `xclip` through a `system` command. For examples of xclip usage, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130968/how-can-i-copy-the-output-of-a-command-directly-into-my-clipboard)

The following Matlab command works for putting multiline stuff into the clipboard on Mac. Presumably you would substitute `pbcopy` with `xclip` and it would work on linux.

```
>> system(['echo "line1' 10 'line2' 10 'line3" | pbcopy'])
```

Comment: yes but how to use it? 
`system("echo 234.4234 | clip.exe")` works well of course, but must things are multi line strings.

Comment: hmm. on windows and octave `system(['echo "line1' 10 'line2' 10 'line3" | pbcopy'])` only outputs `"line1` each new line is interpreted as own command so your statements splits into the commands `echo "line` ,  `line2` and `line3 | pbcopy`

edit: iam wrong it seems that only the first line will be evaluated. the other lines seems to be ignored at all