# How can I copy the output of the last executed command directly into my clipboard?

Tags: bash, terminal, clipboard, zsh, pbcopy

I have seen this post: [how-can-i-copy-the-output-of-a-command-directly-into-my-clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130968/how-can-i-copy-the-output-of-a-command-directly-into-my-clipboard)

I have got this alias

```
# Redoes the last command and copies the output to clipboard

  alias cl="fc -e -|pbcopy"
```

However I would like an alias or a function that **doesn't redo the last command**, but does copy the output of the last command.

Comment: Another relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955577/bash-automatically-capture-output-of-last-executed-command-into-a-variable

Comment: Can we convert the solution to that question into a solution for this one?

Answer (score 1):

Shells in common use on Linux (such as bash) do not preserve the output from the previous command, so re-execution is the only solution unless you add code to do the preservation yourself.  Pbcopy isn't always installed, xclip seems more commonly installed:

```
    ls -l
    !! | xclip
```

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
!-1 | pbcopy
```

or so if you want alias

```
alias cl="!-1 | pbcopy"
```

Comment: this is an inferior version of ```fc -e -|pbcopy``` it wants to redo the last command with the pbcopy behind it and doesn't do so automatically. It needs to only copy the output of the previous command **without redoing the last command**

Comment: ```!!``` is the short version of ```!-1``` btw ;) so who does have the solution?