# How to Write a Huge String to file

Tags: shell, large-data

I have a huge huge string of text that I have on copy / paste , how is the best way to write this to a file. It crashes any GUI text editors I have and when i try use vi / nano it takes forever.

I am running OSX on Macbook Pro i5

Text editors I have tried are textedit, textmate, vi and nano

Comment: "Takes forever" is not very scientific. Since you already have it on the clipboard (that's what I assume you mean when you say "on copy/paste"), open vim with `vim foo.txt`, hit `i`, then paste (`CMD` (the apple logo key) +`V` Terminal), just wait for the text to be pasted, hit `ESC`, then type `:wq` and hit enter.

Comment: Where does the huge string come from? Another file? A web page?

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful :
[pbcopy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbcopy.1.html)

This existing post is also related to your issue :
[Pipe to/from the clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749544/pipe-to-from-clipboard)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
xclip -o > file
```