# Access latest command (not args) from PROMPT_COMMAND

Tags: bash, command-prompt

I have standalone `PROMPT_COMMAND=` in my `.bash_profile`. Every time user input a command, it's being run.
I want to get the first word of the last command by user.

For example, if the user runs: `$ printf "Hey!"`, I want to access `printf` from my `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

`$0` gives me `-bash` and `$1`, `$2`, ... gives me arguments as said on the site below.
https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams#the_first_argument

But how can I access the first word like `printf` in the above example?

Preferably, I want to use the build-in commands as much and cleanly as possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177700/copy-current-command-at-bash-prompt-to-clipboard has some hints but nothing which really solves this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could use **[`fc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html)**:

```
$ printf "%s %s\n" "foo" "bar"
foo bar
$ fc -ln -1
       printf "%s %s\n" "foo" "bar"
```

That prints the entire command with arguments and weird spacing, so I suppose you could do:

```
$ fc -ln -1 | awk '{ print $1 }'
printf
```

**EDIT**: In the case you don't want pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> to come back as `fc` you could do:

```
$ fc -ln -1 | awk '$1 !~ /fc/ {print $1}'
```

To create a **function** in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
# Show last command without args
lcm () { fc -ln -1 | awk '$1 !~ /lcm/ {print $1}' ; }
```

Then for example:

```
$ date
Wed Jan 23 16:29:14 MST 2019
$ lcm
date
```

↳ [GNU : Bash History Built-ins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html)

Comment: Nice trick. But, it won't work when the user's last input is nothing (entering return key) though.

Comment: @I'L'l, I've been trying it out. I am seeing two different behaviors and somehow it's not working yet. When I use it inside `PROMPT_COMMAND`, it prints out the last command as expected but still it's the case as long as user doesn't enter on nothing. When I call just the function, it prints out the last command, not `lcm` if the last command is not empty. Otherwise, it prints out `lcm`.

Comment: Actually, calling function also works the same as in `PROMPT_COMMAND` as described above. Still printing the last command if the user enter nothing. My comment above was wrong as I called lcm after lcm followed by entering nothing a few times.

Comment: Did you reload (source) your `~/.bash_profile` after making the changes? `. ~/.bash_profile`, also are wanting to save the command into a variable?

Comment: I did reload `~/.bash_profile`. I have two functions, one is where I put the command output to variable like `input=$(fc -ln -1 | awk '$1 !~ /fc/ {print $1}')`. Another function is just lcm function that you posted above. Both of them give me the same result.

Comment: Yes, I see. That's a tricky problem. `stdin` appears to ignore the return entered directly after a command for whatever reason and picks up whatever command was before it. I'm not exactly sure why it behaves this way, although maybe there is a way around it somehow; I would need to dive a bit deeper into it though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187216/discussion-between-penguinlay-and-lll).