# Pipe output to paste variable

Tags: bash, unix

I often want to paste things from terminal into my IDE. For example I might want to paste the path to something into the IDE. Is there some way to do

```
bash: pwd > "paste_variable"
```

where the content of "paste_variable" is then what comes out of pressing cmd+v?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the X11 window system (and it's clipboard), you can use `xclip` to access the clipboard from command line:

`paste` :

```
xclip -o             # Write clipboard's contents to stdout
VARIABLE=$(xclip -o) # Write clipboard's contents into a variable
xclip -o | command   # Pipe clipboard contents into command's stdin
```

`copy`:

```
xclip -i "Some text"     # Save static text in the clipboard
xclip -i $(command)      # Save the output of a command into clipboard
command | xclip -i       # Same as above but with a pipe
```

Note: `xclip` will probably not getting installed along with the default X11 installation, you'll need to install it explicitly then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Thanks to this answer I made my way to this question which I didn't find when asking the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749544/pipe-to-from-clipboard Per that answer it can be useful to know that on a Mac you do for example pwd | pbcopy