# How can I add SSH ID to bitbucket?

Tags: ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I am trying to add my SSH ID to bitbucket from my newly installed ArchLinux setup. The instructions for adding my id to bitbucket involve using my browser and copy/paste the key. I am not using a GUI but don't know what the command is to push public keys from commandline to bitbucket. How do I manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the [`links`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_%28web_browser%29) command line browser, although it doesn't seem installed by default. Of course you may want to get the ID [into a clipboard of sorts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750466/589259) if you don't want to type it over.

If the posting the ID doesn't require difficult pages and settings you may be able to implement this using [`httpie`](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie) - which does seem to be installed.

Comment: Just thinking out loud here, didn't try it yet, but you should be able to get it to work.

Comment: OK thanks I will look into your ideas and let you know!

Comment: I used lynx and managed to copy/paste the key. Couldn't submit it though(?) but I am just using the https to retrieve my repos. Will try again at a later date.