# Bash command line on linux copying and pasting

Tags: copy-paste

I need to copy a pdf file from the bash command line. I have trouble using cp. An error message appears. If I can copy it, I am hoping that it is stored as a variable. That's all. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cI1I.png) Here's an image file of the example for more simple and detailed situation.

Comment: Please avoid using images for textual content (like code/error message/text output). Also please clarify what you actually trying to achieve.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749544/pipe-to-from-clipboard

Answer (score 0):

1) you typed "cd" into the command line, not "cp"

2) to use 'cp' you need to type [ cp (inputfile) (outputfile) ]

Comment: use [ tab ]  to auto-complete the file names for input, and then see if that helps. (spaces can cause issues in 'path' variables)

Comment: That would release the copied document immediately. I can't do that. It needs to be saved as a variable. So I can use it later.

I would use that copied document and upload it into a website later. How can we fix this problem?

Comment: Ohh, you just don't then. You store a "conceptual pointer" (the path of the file) in your bash script. then you use that path name later to read the file as input to some other command.

Comment: Thank you the tab is a great function. I will look into the very last answer now, it's a difficult concept for me.