# Copy Terminal Output For GUI Pasting

Tags: linux, xorg

I'm trying to redirect output from the terminal to a file (or variable) so I can then paste the content to a GUI program. Like so:

```
$ echo "Text to be pasted" >> /path/to/file
```

And then paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in a browser.

Which file or variable is that in a Linux system?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749544/pipe-to-from-the-clipboard-in-bash-script

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: Yes it does, thank you.