# gpg decrypting and moving a file safely

Tags: bash, unix

I want to decrypt and move a file safely.
What would be the safest way to do this?
My current approach:

```
echo "what's the passphrase?"
read -s -r key
gpg --decrypt --batch --passphrase "$key" "file.gpg" > file
mv -f "./file" "/location/file"
```

Are there any security issues that might occur this way?

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is ok, but it depends on what you want to achieve. Although:

> "As long as you don't move the file across file-system borders, the operation should be safe" - [ref](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164582/45200).

If your priority is safety, and you don't own the system you are working on, I would consider not saving content in the file, rather copying the content directly to the clipboard (using `xclip` [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4208191/1977012) or `clipboard-cli`, if you can install it). Then you could safely store your data in a desired secure destination. In the end, [emptying the buffer's cache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87909/45200) would be a final step.

For larger files (measured in GB or more), I think saving the file on the system would be required. Then after a successful copying of it across file-system borders, you would need to clean it up - `shred` or `wipe` ([ref](https://askubuntu.com/a/57580/168174)) would be your friends here.