# Does the MacOS Clipboard have a path to it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, clipboard, pyperclip

I am currently working on a python program that makes use of the clipboard. If you want to know more, I am finding a way to access clipboard history, which is very hard to find for free. I then realized I had no idea how to access the clipboard. My main question is, is there a way to access the clipboard and read what it says through python with any module? Or, does the MacOS Clipboard have a path that I can use to read the file and get the clipboard?

I only used two modules, pyperclip and clipboard. These two apparently only have the copy & paste function.

Comment: I found this post enlightening on the topic of interacting with clipboards programmatically:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749544/pipe-to-from-the-clipboard-in-a-bash-script

Comment: There is no file, and thus no path. The clipboard only exists in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In macOS, once you copy something else, the previous item disappears. macOS clipboard is designed to hold one item at a time.

To get the last clipboard item in python use this:

```
import pyperclip as pc

clipboard = pc.paste()
print(clipboard)
```

A solution to your query:

1. Run a code that checks the `pc.paste()` value periodically(e.g. every second) for any change and adds the new value to a variable/file that preserves a history of the records.
2. Same as number 1 but instead of adopting a periodical approach, watches `pc.paste()` for any change using python `pdb` [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). It's for debugging but you can trace any change in the value of a variable using `pdb.set_trace()` function.

Comment: Thanks, now I know the paste command actually stores the current clipboard data.